# how to add fullscreen button above VLC player in swift

Tags: ios, swift, vlc, libvlc

I want to add button fullscreen in top of VLC video player. I try this code but it's not working:

```
    class VideoScreen: UIViewController{

    @IBOutlet weak var playerView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var indicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnFullSrc: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var playerViewHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!

    var b : Bool = false;

    let player: VLCMediaPlayer = {
        let p = VLCMediaPlayer(options: ["--extraintf="])
        return p!
    }();

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        title = "Xem camera"

        self.initPlayer()
    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        player.stop()
    }

    func initPlayer() {
        let streamUrl = URL(string: rstpFactoryUrl)
        let media = VLCMedia(url: streamUrl)

        player.media = media
        player.delegate = self
        player.drawable = playerView

        player.play()
        (player.drawable as! UIView).bringSubview(toFront: btnFullSrc)
    }
}
```

Here is my storyboard UI:

[image]

When video is running the 'btnFullSrc' is hidden likely the video frame always on top. Any help here thanks you

UPDATE: I change code to

```
self.view.bringSubview(toFront: btnFullSrc)
```

but still not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your button is a subview of the video view. This is not supported by VLCKit. You need to have the button at the same hierarchy level or above to have it displayed on top of the video.

Comment: It work thanks you much. Now i try to get image preview of rstp stream video like thumbnail like your tutorial :https://www.feepk.net/2018/03/13/mobilevlckit-and-vlckit-part-3/. But it still working. Can you help

Comment: the log always display: **WARNING: media thumbnailer media thumbnailing timed out**

Answer (score 0):

Your current is bringing the VLC screen to the front.
If you want to bring the button to the front, you should do this:

```
self.view.bringSubview(toFront: btnFullSrc)
```

or do this:

```
playerView.bringSubview(toFront: btnFullSrc)
```

Comment: where you are calling the initPlayer? try calling to bringSubview in viewDidAppear

Comment: still not working, when video is playing, the button disappear.

Comment: try this:  self.view. sendSubviewToBack(player.drawable as! UIView)